# Rigol DS1052E shows random noise signal after encoder panel replacement

Tags: oscilloscope

My Rigol suffered a failure of the rotary encoder panel board so I got a replacement from Rigol and made the swap.

Now when I use the scope, channel 1 and 2 both just show a noise signal, whether or not a sensible signal is sent to those channels (i.e. I see the same thing even with no probe plugged in).

This video shows channel 1 being displayed while hooked up to the device's built in oscillator.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpQEnlvEbYc

Any ideas on where to start debugging this?

(The new rotary encoder board is working by the way.)[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot, earn an upvote.

Comment: Well, you'd do a thorough visual inpection for disturbed connections and dead components before checking voltages.

Comment: Have added a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 
Press     →Self-Cal, enter the Self-Calibration interface Run

Step 2
Get Service [manual](http://frankshospitalworkshop.com/equipment/documents/workshop_equipment/manuals/Rigol_DS-1000_Digital_Oscilloscope_-_Service_guide.pdf) follow procedures or get quote from authorized Rigol service centre

Step 3 follow Andrew's sage advice